# Como puedo recorrer un componente Badged en React js

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, reactjs

tengo un problema con un badged ya que no puedo recórrelos, el prop que recibo para poder poblar el badged si se recibe bien y se ponen los badgeds bien pero solo se crea uno,
este es mi componente y en el componente `<Badged variant='dark'>{tags}</Badged>` es en donde mando los tags que quiero que aparescan.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero ya en el resultado se ve así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Comment: Y por qué no iteras el prop tags y en cada iteración pintas el componente Badged?

Comment: para serte sincero estoy aprendiendo aun react, se que esa es una forma pero aun no encontré un ejemplo que me pudiera ayudar, en algunos ejemplos vi que lo hacían iterando con un for pero intente aplicarlo pero me daba error al intentar aplicarlo al componente

Comment: tags es un string o un array?

Comment: Es un arreglo, desde un componente padre hago un map y aca ya solo recibo los props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que mencionas que tags es un arreglo, podrías hacer algo así:

```
cons badges = tags.map((badge, index) => <Badged key={index} variant=“dark”>{badge}</Badged>
```

Y ya en la parte de tu código donde pones el Badged tendrías que poner lo que regresa el map

```
{badges}
```

Comment: Perfecto, ahora lo pruebo. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Quedó perfecto amigo, si funcionó, de verdad te agradezco mucho la ayuda  ya tenía unos días encontrando una solución.